# How can I take out dog diarrhea stain from unfinished pine floor?

Tags: floor

My fog had an accident a few days ago on the unfinished pine floor we have in the living room. After cleaning it wish basic cleaning products it left quite a stain. 
I would appreciate any kind of help into what products I should use and buy as soon as possible to restore the wood at least close to its original state! 
Thank you! [image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This is  likely to be deemed off-topic, but that said my best solution would be to sand it off, and get a diaper for the dog.

Comment: tell everybody that it's a bloodstain from the last guy that annoyed you .... lol

Answer (score 1):

Unfinished wood is tough because the nasties in the diarrhea have soaked into the wood fibers. to get the stain out you might end up bleaching the wood. I would try a weak hydrogen peroxide and water solution. Peroxide may take some of the color out but I think it would be less harmful than bleach and water. The products that take pet stains out of carpet probably won't work in this case. Another possibility is a real steam cleaner, my wife has a lady bug steam cleaner and it is amazing how well it works, a steam iron with a damp towel may work similarly. I think any stronger cleaners like trisodium phosphate will also bleach the coloring, since the floor was unfinished the stain might be fairly deep so I would try hydrogen peroxide 3% to water or steam cleaning prior to anything stronger.